# prolog:query that search about range in list

Tags: prolog

I need to write query that search in given range in list

I try this but it does not work

```
find(R1, R2, Z, L):-
    D=1,
    element_at(X, Z, D),
    X >= R1,
    X <= R2,
    add(X, L, [X|L]),
    D+1.
```

it give me `false`

but I need to return the list that contain integers in this range

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what the semantics of this are supposed to be? What does `element_at/3` do? What does `add/3` do?

Comment: element at index D and Z is list and X list returned it built in predicate

Comment: add/3 add to list it also built in

Comment: These comments are not helping at all. You still don't explain what the predicate is supposed to do exaclty. What implementation are you using? Can you show what you are getting and what you expect to get?

Comment: i ask how to search in about range of integers in list and return all those integers in list

Comment: Why wouldn't you show an example query, the output you get, and the expected output?

Comment: it give false but the expected return the list of integers in given range?

Comment: Are you being stubborn? Just edit your question, so that it contains the **exact query**, **the output you get**, and **the expected output**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I have understood the question, I think that you can do that : 
**Answer edited**

```
% when the list is empty, there is nothing between R1 and R2
find(_R1, _R2, [], []).

% I test the first element of the list
% then I process the rest of the list
% L1 is unified after the call of find
find(R1, R2, [[Age, Name] | T], L):-
    (   (R1 =< Age, Age =< R2)
    ->  L = [Name | L1]
    ;   L = L1),
    find(R1, R2, T, L1).
```

Comment: thanks for reply if i enter query like this how to do this?

find(10,30,[[60,john],[24,alex]],L).

then return just alex

how to do this please help.

Comment: also how can find number of checks in order to build the output list

Comment: but last thing i need to find number of checks in order to build the output list